# Kentico Document Get Page Meta Data Custom Page Type

Tags: kentico

When trying to retrieve `DocumentPageTitle` and `DocumentPageDescription` using `GetStringValue()` on a custom page type TreeNode, the result is always coming back as the default value (in this case an empty string) passed into the method.

I'm able to successfully retrieve other column values as well as standard document properties such as `DocumentName`, `DocumentID` and `AbsoluteURL`, but not the document meta properties.

The respective fields in the **Meta** tab of document/page do have values and are being successfully rendered in the  by default such as `<meta name="description" content=".." />`

```
// returns empty string
string documentPageDescription = DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.GetString("DocumentPageDescription", string.Empty);

// returns empty string
TreeNode document = parameters[0] as TreeNode;
string documentPageDescription = document.GetStringValue("DocumentPageDescription", string.Empty);
```

I've tried setting option **Inherits fields from page type** to "Page (menu item)", but that did not help.

Does the custom page type need to inherit from something specifically or have a specific setting activated to access these values? Or if what I think is a `TreeNode` in fact isn't, how could I get the TreeNode from this object that has the properties listed before available?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DocumentPageTitle` and `DocumentPageDescription` were coming back as null when the custom page type document/page was inheriting from parent/global values.

I was able to use the following to get the properties when **not** inheriting, while falling back to the parent value when inheriting was taking place:

```
string documentPageTitle = document.GetStringValue("DocumentPageTitle", DocumentContext.CurrentTitle);
```

This approach came from the following issue on [Kentico DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/getting-the-metadata-of-a-page-via-expression).

Thank you for your help and suggestions, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
ValidationHelper.GetString(CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.GetValue("DocumentPageDescription"), string.Empty)
```

Comment: Please don't just post code here. Try to explain why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check, one, are you sure the meta data is available on the page you are pulling? Two, is your API actually pulling all the data for that page?

I've used these in my test and both returned the metadata.

```
var page = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Path("/Articles/Coffee-Beverages-Explained").FirstObject;
Response.Write(page.GetStringValue("DocumentPageDescription", string.Empty));

TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
TreeNode tn = tree.SelectNodes().OnCurrentSite().Path("/Articles/Coffee-Beverages-Explained").FirstObject;
Response.Write(tn.GetStringValue("DocumentPageDescription", string.Empty));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think my issue was relating to the [following](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/getting-the-metadata-of-a-page-via-expression). If the custom page type page was set to inherit from parent, the result was coming back as null. I was able to get the parent meta values in the inherit situation via `DocumentContext.CurrentTitle` and `DocumentContext.CurrentDescription`. When not inheriting, getting the value via `GetStringValue()` on the `TreeNode` object worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: I see, because when inheriting from parent, there is no actual data stored in the Description column for that item, thus the GetValue or GetStringVlaue gets null.